# How can I check the type of a NewType value?

Tags: python, mypy, typing, newtype, pyright

How do you check the value of `NewType` against its basic type `str` without casting and mixing up type checking?

I declared a new type:

```py
BoardId = NewType("BoardId", str)
```

that I use as a method parameter either as a single value or as an `Iteration` other than  `str`.

I use `instanceof` to check if the type is `str` and not `Tuple` then I convert it to a tuple otherwise use it as it is.
The problem `pyright` things `BoardId` is `str` because of `isinstance` which fails the type checking.
On the other hand, I cannot use `isinstance` against `NewType` since:

`TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union`

Leaving as it is

```py
    async def get_stickies(
        self, board_id: Union[BoardId, Iterable[BoardId]]
    ) -> List[Sticky]:
        board_ids: Iterable[BoardId] = (
            (board_id,) if isinstance(board_id, str) else board_id
        )
```

causes this issue:

```
Diagnostics:                                                                                                                      
1. Expression of type "tuple[BoardId | str] | Iterable[BoardId]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Iterable[BoardId]"
     Type "tuple[BoardId | str] | Iterable[BoardId]" cannot be assigned to type "Iterable[BoardId]"
       TypeVar "_T_co@Iterable" is covariant
         Type "BoardId | str" cannot be assigned to type "BoardId"
           "str" is incompatible with "BoardId"
```

[image]

Comment: someone else will give you a proper answer, but your problem dealing with `board_id: Union[BoardId, Iterable[BoardId]]` is a sign that it's a bad design... IMHO (with exception of `Optional`) Union types should only be used for types that can "duck type" for each other, rather than dissimilar types like `thing` and `list[thing]`... e.g. force your callers to pre-wrap a single board-id (they probably already know which they have?), then your method can be just `board_ids: Iterable[BoardId]`

Comment: I don't know if there's a cleverer way, but you could `(cast(BoardId, board_id),)`

Answer (score 0):

One solution was proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3325):

```py
from typing import Iterable, TypeAlias, NewType

_BoardIdT: TypeAlias = str
BoardId = NewType('BoardId', _BoardIdT)

def get_stickies(board_id: BoardId | Iterable[BoardId]) -> None:
    board_ids: Iterable[BoardId] = (
        (board_id,) if isinstance(board_id, _BoardIdT) else board_id
    )
```

[Playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=77a756d7ef10856152fce273828f42be)

The underlying type is accessible via `BoardId.__supertype__`, but `mypy` doesn't like this undocumented attribute.